# Exercism: Poetry Club Door Policy. When running well locally but not on exercism... Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on Poetry Club Door Policy practice on Exercism.

However, I run my code on Visual Studio which works perfectly!!!

But in exercism, it returns error... (doesn't pass the test).

What wrong with my code or (Exercism)?

```
export function backDoorResponse(line) {
  var newWord = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    let aSingleLine = line[i].trim();
    let lastWord = aSingleLine[aSingleLine.length - 1];
    newWord.push(lastWord);
  }
  return newWord;
}
```

Project Requirement:

**Get the last letter of a sentence.**

When the guard recites Stands so high, you'll respond h, when the guard recites Huge hooves too, you'll respond o.

Note that sometimes the guard does stylistic pauses (in the form of whitespace) at the beginning or at the end of a line. You will need to ignore those pauses to derive the correct letter.

Implement the function backDoorResponse that takes a line of the poem as an argument and returns the last letter of that line that is not a whitespace character.

[image]

My result on VS:

[image]

The error message from Exercism:
[image]

Thanks a lot!!!!
I am so new to this computer world ...

Comment: Hi, please try to use text instead of images when possible.

Comment: I thought images are much easier to communicate ...

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You're returning an array. You're supposed to return a single character.

Comment: `line[i]` is a single character in the input string. So you're just converting the input string to an array of characters, except that space characters are converted to `undefined`.

Comment: Your code seems to expect `line` to be an array of strings, and it returns the last character of each string. But it's just one string, not an array.

Comment: The `recite()` function takes the array, and calls `backDoorResponse()` on each of them. You don't need to process the array in your function.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much ! 

``` 
export function backDoorResponse(line) {
  line.trim();
  let lineLength = line.length;
  return line[lineLength - 1];
}
```

I solved the first one Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar


But still I got the other errors...

Error Message:

`const SHIRE_HORSE_WITH_SPACES = [
      'Stands so high   ',
      '\tHuge hooves too\t',
      'Impatiently waits for \t \t',
      '    Reins and harness    ',
      'Eager to leave\n\n',
    ];
const actualLetters = recite(SHIRE_HORSE_WITH_SPACES, backDoorResponse);
const expectedLetters = ['h', 'o', 'r', 's', 'e'];
expect(actualLetters).toStrictEqual(expectedLetters);`

Comment: `line.trim()` should be `line = line.trim()`

Answer (score -1):

The argument is a single line, not an array of lines, so you don't need the loop.

```js
function backDoorResponse(line) {
  let aSingleLine = line.trim();
  return aSingleLine[aSingleLine.length - 1];
}

console.log(backDoorResponse('Stands so high'));
console.log(backDoorResponse('Stands so high     '));
```